# Is there a tool to check proofs of haskell code properties?

Tags: haskell, proof, proof-of-correctness

There are ways (for example, https://jeltsch.wordpress.com/2012/04/30/dependently-typed-programming-and-theorem-proving-in-haskell/, PromotedDataKinds extension) to fake dependent types in haskell, and this makes it possible to prove some code properties in haskell itself.

Examples of properties I may want proved include totality of some function or monad laws for somr Monad typeclass instance.

Such a proof would be a value (a::T) where T represents the statement we've proved. Unfortunately, in haskell we can write terms of false type, e. g. (fix id::forall a.a), so we can actually prove everything. Is there  a tool to check proof correctness or monad laws satisfaction in haskell? 
Does anybody include proofs in source code?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I don't think what you are trying to do is actually a good idea. I mean: sure do use the type system to provide some guarantees and avoid most errors, but since the logics is unsound you cannot achieve what you actually want. If you are looking for formally correct code you could use (e.g.) Coq and then extract programs from it.

Comment: In any case questions asking about finding a tool/resource ecc. are *off topic* for stackoverflow. You should probably ask this on some mailing list/subreddit or stuff like that.

Comment: Andy Gill had a student working in this and Levent had recently released a tool that does something similar.

Comment: Also, you might be interested in Liquid Haskell.

Comment: @Bakuriu sorry this post is off topic. Should i delete it?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Thanks, that tool by Levent seems like what i want.